# I can't query all my data from the database when using DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I have an SQL query here wherein it returns
Notice: Undefined index: sbvip

because i'm using SELECT DISTINCT, I can't query the other columns
I need to avoid duplicate records thats why I used DISTINCT.

meanwhile, when I use SELECT * , there are no errors but duplicate records are showing..

below is my sql query

```
function setvip_sportsbook_model(){
 //connect to the server
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","people");
//check the connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno($conn)){
echo "Error";
}
else{
//echo "connect Ok";    
}


 //prepare the sql

$sql= "SELECT DISTINCT merchant_name FROM merchants2";
//execute query
$result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
//process result
if($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $record = array();
do{
    
    $info['merchant_name']=$myrow['merchant_name'];
    $info['sbvip']=$myrow['sbvip'];

    
    $record[] = $info;
    
}while($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
 }  
   return $record;
 }
```

can help me what query i need to do for the sbvip? thank you a lot

Comment: Can you add output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE merchants2`, because how would we know what `sbvip` is ?

Comment: sbvip is one of the column name of table merchants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change sql to

`$sql= "SELECT DISTINCT merchant_name, sbvip FROM merchants2";`

this will select only records that have a distinct merchant_name and sbvip value.

however, it sounds worrisome that you have duplicate records in your database at all. what if one gets updated but not the other? then you have old version and new versions of the same record in the same database giving inconsistent results.

another tip, your record retrieving loop can be rewritten as this:

```
$record = array();
while($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    
    $info['merchant_name']=$myrow['merchant_name'];
    $info['sbvip']=$myrow['sbvip'];

    
    $record[] = $info;
    
}
```

you can remove the first `if($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){`. this will also help in the case that no records are found, preventing the return value from being null.

Comment: also, now that I think about it, i don't see where $info is defined as an array or object. this may cause issues in your code as well.

Comment: thank you for the answers dqhendricks, and info was on use to get the value from the database with merchant_name and sbvip column name